# Multiple controllers with redundant action logic in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, controller, composition, api-design

I have 3 controllers. Two returning specialized items (Article, Announcement), and one returning either.

```
GET api/announcements/1 -- produces Announcement json
GET api/articles/2      -- produces Article json
GET api/posts/1         -- produces Announcement json
GET api/posts/2         -- produces Article json
```

the `show` method for the Articles Controller contains logic that would have to be duplicated in the Posts Controller. More specifically:

```
def show
  deal_with_params(...)
  authorize!(...)
  render json: @resource
end
```

After I fetch the resource by `unique_id`, I know it's type and can branch out from there, but I only want to `authorize` and do some other operations on resources of type `Article`.

Anyone have recommendations, patterns, or ideas that would help to make sure that changes to that `ArticlesController#show` would not have to be repeated in Posts Controller?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [controller concerns](http://elegantbrew.tumblr.com/post/70990048275/controller-concerns-in-rails-4) to extract the common functionality. For your specific use case, you could have two concerns:

- An `AnnouncementsConcern` which has all the code required to deal with `Announcements`.
- An `ArticlesConcern` which has all the code for dealing with `Articles`.

Then you'd include these concerns in the controllers as needed. I.e. you would include `AnnouncementsConcern` in `AnnouncementsController` and `ArticlesConcern` in `ArticlesController`, then include both concerns in `PostsController`.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this so late. This looks like a cool idea, but I'm having a hard time implementing it. I don't think I understand how the PostsController is supposed to call the methods in the concerns.   
So I have two pieces:
(1) `show` method that has `authorize!(...) if @resource.type == 'Article'`.  
(2) `deal_with_params(...)` that has the same conditional.  
Can you give me an example of `ArticlesConcern`,  `PostsController`, and maybe ArticlesController.

Answer (score 0):

You can dry it up by using inheritance. This is an example of an extremly dry base controller using [Pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit), [Responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) and [jsonapi](http://jsonapi.org/)

```
class ResourcesController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :json

  before_action :authenticate_user # use a secure by default model
  before_action :set_resource, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize_resource, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_resources, only: [:index]

  def create
    @resource = resource_class.create(permitted_attributes) do |r|
      yield(r) if block_given?
    end
    respond_with(@resource)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@resource)
  end

  def index
    respond_with(@resources)
  end

  def update
    @resource.update(permitted_attributes) do |r|
      yield(r) if block_given?
    end
    respond_with(@resource)
  end

  def destroy
    @resource.destroy
    respond_with(@resource)
  end


  private 

  def set_resource
    @resource = resource_class.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_resources
    @resources = policy_scope(resource_class)
  end

  def authorize_resource
    authorize( @resource )
  end

  def resource_class
    self.class.controller_name.classify.constantize
  end

  def permitted_attributes
    whitelist = policy(@resource || self.class.resource_class)
                      .permitted_attributes
    params.require(:data).require(:attributes).permit(whitelist)
  end
end
```

There are a few really nifty tricks here:

- `self.class.controller_name.classify.constantize` uses convention over configuration to guess the model based on the controller name.
- Using `before_action` callbacks lets subclasses opt out by using `skip_before_action` or change the behaviour by declaring the callback methods.
- Using `yield` lets subclasses tap into the flow of the controller.
- the JSON API format uses the same data format regardless of the entity instead of the rails default of using `model_name.param_key` as the root param key. Less bikeshed painting is a good thing.

Example of a subclasses:

```
# Nothing special going on here
class ThingsController < ResourcesController; end

class ArticlesController < ResourcesController
  def create 
    # taps into the yield
    super do |article|
      article.author = current_user
    end
  end
end

class StranglyNamedController < ResourcesController
  def resource_class
    Thing
  end
end
```

Comment: You can of course combine this with module mixins (concerns).